# Need an effecient way for bucketing date difference

Tags: r, lubridate

I need to bucket date difference into user specified list of buckets. Since the data size is big I dont want to use loops. I am looking for something like apply (or its variants) functions in R

I have written the code which does the same thing but using For loop, which I want to avoid, since its taking lots of time. 
There is a user defined function 'FunTenor', which calculates the tenor. It is called for each element from inside the Loop. 
Have used package `lubridate` and `data.table`.

```
Dates = data.frame(VAL_DATE = c("2015-07-27","2015-09-15","2016-06-24","2016-06-23","2015-09-17","2015-06-22"), MAT_DATE = c("2016-07-27","2016-09-15","2016-08-08","2017-06-23","2016-09-16","2017-06-22"))

FunTenor <- function(x) { if(x@year*12+x@month ==0) (if(x@day<=1) "1D" else if(x@day<=7) "7D" else if(x@day<=14) "14D" else "1M") else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=2) "2M" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=3) "3M" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=6) "6M" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=12) "1Y" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=36) "3Y" else "5Y"}

dtDiff = as.period(interval( ymd(Dates$VAL_DATE), ymd(Dates$MAT_DATE)))
TenorDiff = data.frame(Bucket = c())
for(i in seq(1,length(dtDiff))){
  TenorDiff = rbind(TenorDiff, data.frame(Bucket = FunTenor(dtDiff[i])))
}
print(TenorDiff)
```

I have tried using things like :

```
lapply(dtDiff, FunTenor)
```

It throws error :

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>         trying to get slot "year" from an object of a basic class ("numeric") with no slots.

In fact if I call, `FunTenor("1m 15d 0H 0M 0S")`, it throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing from a loop to iterating with a functional like `lapply()` or `map()` won’t make your code significantly faster. Those functions still do a loop under the hood; they just take care of some of the boilerplate code that you need to store the result.

The way to improve performance by orders of magnitude here, is to re-write `FunTenor()` to work with a vector argument rather than a scalar one. Here’s one way to do that:

```r
tenor <- function(x) {
  months <- year(x) * 12 + month(x)

  ifelse(months == 0,
    as.character(cut(day(x),
                     breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 7, 14, Inf),
                     labels = c("1D", "7D", "14D", "1M"))),
    as.character(cut(months,
                     breaks = c(-Inf, 2, 3, 6, 12, 36, Inf),
                     labels = c("2M", "3M", "6M", "1Y", "3Y", "5Y")))
  )
}
```

And here’s a benchmark with 10 000 periods to show the difference:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

Dates <- data.frame(VAL_DATE = c("2015-07-27", "2015-09-15", "2016-06-24", "2016-06-23", "2015-09-17", "2015-06-22"), MAT_DATE = c("2016-07-27", "2016-09-15", "2016-08-08", "2017-06-23", "2016-09-16", "2017-06-22"))

dtDiff <- as.period(interval(ymd(Dates$VAL_DATE), ymd(Dates$MAT_DATE)))

FunTenor <- function(x) {
  if (x@year * 12 + x@month == 0) (if (x@day <= 1) "1D" else if (x@day <= 7) "7D" else if (x@day <= 14) "14D" else "1M") else if ((x@year * 12 + x@month) <= 2) "2M" else if ((x@year * 12 + x@month) <= 3) "3M" else if ((x@year * 12 + x@month) <= 6) "6M" else if ((x@year * 12 + x@month) <= 12) "1Y" else if ((x@year * 12 + x@month) <= 36) "3Y" else "5Y"
}

set.seed(42)

x <- dtDiff[sample(length(dtDiff), 10000, replace = TRUE)]

print(microbenchmark(map_chr(x, FunTenor), tenor(x), times = 2), digits = 2)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                  expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max neval cld
#>  map_chr(x, FunTenor) 4641.5 4641.5 4662.8 4662.8 4684.1 4684.1     2   b
#>              tenor(x)    4.4    4.4    6.5    6.5    8.5    8.5     2  a
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

Comment: This is a very efficient solution. In your function `tenor`  year(x), month(x), etc. doesnt works for me. It should be replaced by x@year, x@month, etc; and its still much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, both `sapply` and `lapply` returns an error but it works with `map` variants

```
purrr::map_chr(dtDiff, FunTenor)
#[1] "1Y" "1Y" "2M" "1Y" "1Y" "3Y"
```

`FunTenor` function is written to handle objects of `"Period"` class which `dtDiff` is,

```
class(dtDiff)
#[1] "Period"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "lubridate"
```

when used in `sapply` or `lapply` it cannot handle that(?) and converts it to numeric instead. While the attempt `FunTenor("1m 15d 0H 0M 0S")` is of character class hence the error.

Comment: `*apply()` functions coerce their argument into a list before iterating. `"Period"` is an S4 class whose `as.list()` method returns just a list with the `.Data` slot, which is why it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider to vectorize your function and pass in the entire vector into the function.

```
FunTenor <- Vectorize(function(x) { if(x@year*12+x@month ==0) (if(x@day<=1) "1D" else if(x@day<=7) "7D" else if(x@day<=14) "14D" else "1M") else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=2) "2M" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=3) "3M" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=6) "6M" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=12) "1Y" else if((x@year*12+x@month)<=36) "3Y" else "5Y"})

dtDiff = as.period(interval( ymd(Dates$VAL_DATE), ymd(Dates$MAT_DATE)))
TenorDiff = setNames(data.frame(data = matrix((FunTenor(dtDiff))), stringsAsFactors = F), "Bucket")

> print(TenorDiff)
  Bucket
1     1Y
2     1Y
3     2M
4     1Y
5     1Y
6     3Y
```